# Pop off empty field

Tags: python, list

I have some messy IMBD data.

I'm running a script which isolates unambiguous fields - id, year, and rank - and surrounds the remaining name field with quotes.

I'd like to amend the script to place a 0 in the 'rank' field wherever there is missing data.  Without this change, the `pop` function fails to account for the field, affecting how the script counts and condenses the name field.

How can I add a 0 to the 'rank' field where there is currently nothing?

Here is a snapshot of the data.

```
id,name,year,rank
0,#28 (2002),2002,
1,#7 Train: An Immigrant Journey, The (2000),2000,
2,$ (1971),1971,6.4000000000000004
3,$1,000 Reward (1913),1913,
4,$1,000 Reward (1915),1915,
5,$1,000 Reward (1923),1923,
6,$1,000,000 Duck (1971),1971,5
7,$1,000,000 Reward, The (1920),1920,
8,$10,000 Under a Pillow (1921),1921,
9,$100,000 (1915),1915,
10,$100,000 Pyramid, The (2001),2001,
11,$1000 a Touchdown (1939),1939,6.7000000000000002
```

Here is my working script.

```
f = open("IMDBMovie.txt")
print(next(f)) # header
for line in f:
    fields = line.strip().split(",")

    # Get unambiguous fields.
    id = fields.pop(0)
    rank = fields.pop(-1)
    year = fields.pop(-1)

    # Surround name with quotes.
    name = '"{}"'.format(",".join(fields))
    print("{},{},{},{}".format(id, name, year, rank))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that syntax:

```
print("{},{},{},{}".format(id, name, year, rank if rank else 0))
#                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the Python's version of the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).